# why is numpy apply_along_axis not working

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

below is two numpy ndarrays which has the same rows but in a different order.  When I apply function g1 by row I would expect to get the same results back but in a different order. This is not the case however.

```
g1(x):
   return max(0, (x[0] - 1)**2 + (x[1] - 1)**2 - 1.05**2)

Case1:
sol1 = np.array(
        [
            [0, 0],
            [1, 1],
            [0, 1],
            [1, 0],
            [0.2, 0.7],
            [0.5, 0.5],
            [0.75, 0],
            [0.25, 0.8],
            [0.5, 0.6],
            [0.2, 0.7],
        ]
)
v = numpy.apply_along_axis(g1, 1, sol1)

This produce: [ 0.8975, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.] as expected.
Case2:
# The same array with rows shuffled.
sols = numpy.array(
        [
            [0, 1],
            [0.2, 0.7],
            [0.5, 0.5],
            [0.75, 0],
            [0.2, 0.7],
            [1, 0],
            [0.25, 0.8],
            [0.5, 0.6],
            [0, 0],
            [1, 1],
        ]
)
v = numpy.apply_along_axis(g1, 1, sols)
This produces: [ 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.] which is wrong.
Should be: [ 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.8975, 0.]
```

My system is:
numpy: 1.13.1 :
python: 3.6.2 :
Win10 Pro     :
conda : 4.3.27

Thanks

Comment: Try returning 'max (0.0, ...)', i.e a float in all cases.

Comment: That worked for both cases, thanks very much.  I am just trying to understand why that made all the difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recreating your calculation:

```
In [25]: def g1(x):
    ...:     return max(0,  (x[0] - 1)**2 + (x[1] - 1)**2 - 1.05**2)
    ...: 
In [26]: g1([0,0])
Out[26]: 0.8975
In [27]: g1([1,1])
Out[27]: 0
In [28]: np.apply_along_axis(g1,1,[[0,0],[1,1]])
Out[28]: array([ 0.8975,  0.    ])
In [29]: np.apply_along_axis(g1,1,[[1,1],[0,0],[1,1]])
Out[29]: array([0, 0, 0])
```

Notice the `Out[29]` is an integer array, not the float that you describe (that's not a copy-n-paste is it?).

`apply_along_axis` uses a trial calculation to determine the return dtype.    If the first case returns integers, then then it creates an integer array to take the results.  Assigning a float to an integer array results in  truncation.

I've seen this problem with `np.vectorize`, and suspected it was also happening here.  We could look at the code for `apply_along_axis` to verify where and how it's happening.

So changing `g1` to `max(0.0, ...)` ensures that the function always returns a float, and `apply` returns the correct dtype.

---

The relevant piece of code:

```
res = asanyarray(func1d(inarr_view[ind0], *args, **kwargs))

# build a buffer for storing evaluations of func1d.
# remove the requested axis, and add the new ones on the end.
# laid out so that each write is contiguous.
# for a tuple index inds, buff[inds] = func1d(inarr_view[inds])
buff = zeros(inarr_view.shape[:-1] + res.shape, res.dtype)
```

Comment: Great, thx for the explanation. It is fairly subtle and can cause some problems for sure. I will be  more diligent with this in future.